# Why doesn't background color behind Unordered list change?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nav bar with a search bar within the nav bar. The problem is that the background color behind the unordered list part of the nav bar is just white like the rest of the page. Shouldn't it be the background color I set it to?
HTML

```
<div class="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/"> Home </a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/"> Home </a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="searchbar input-group col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control py-2" type="search" placeholder="Search..." id="example-search-input">
        <span class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.searchbar {
  float:right;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.topnav {
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Comment: Floated child elements cause the parent element to collapse. See the duplicate question above (which is a duplicate itself, so check out that as well) for solutions/work arounds.

Comment: `ul{ overflow: hidden; }` will fix your problem. The alternative is not to use `float` at all and display the `<li>`s using flexbox: `ul { display: flex; align-items: center;}`

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/dLc3sqbv/) flexbox applied to your example. I used it for both `.topbar` and the `<ul>` and I removed the floats. Depending on context, additional CSS might be required.